# Result column based on multiple conditions pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have following df:

```
data = [
    ['ok', 'ok', 'ok'],
    ['ok', 'nok', 'nok'],
    ['deact', 'ok', 'ok'],
    ['deact', 'ok', 'nok'],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

I want to have new column result as follows

```
    col1 col2 col3 result
0     ok   ok   ok     ok
1     ok  nok  nok    nok
2  deact   ok   ok  deact
3  deact   ok  nok    nok
```

Where if any column contains nok, result also equals to nok,
and if result is ok and any column contains deact, the result should be deact.
How to do it most efficiently since table contains 50 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Classical approach using [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['result'] = np.select([df.eq('nok').any(axis=1),
                          df.eq('deact').any(axis=1)],
                         ['nok', 'deact'], 'ok')
```

Or, using an ordered [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical) (with [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html)) to specify the priority of the values:

```
order = pd.CategoricalDtype(['nok', 'deact', 'ok'], ordered=True)

df['result'] = df.astype(order).min(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    col1 col2 col3 result
0     ok   ok   ok     ok
1     ok  nok  nok    nok
2  deact   ok   ok  deact
3  deact   ok  nok    nok
```

Comment: thank you for helping, what if i have muliple input conditions. For example ('nok' or 'not exist') should be 'nok' in result column and ('ok' or 'nor found') = 'ok'

Comment: @KokeAbeke then add each condition in the `select` for example `np.select([df.eq('nok').any(axis=1) | df.eq('not exist').any(axis=1), df.eq('deact').any(axis=1)], ['nok', 'deact'], 'ok')` or `np.select([np.isin(df, ['nok', 'not exists']).any(axis=1), df.eq('deact').any(axis=1)], ['nok', 'deact'], 'ok')`

Comment: `numpy.select` is always easy to use (and relatively efficient), you just make a list of your conditions, a list of the values, a default value if no condition match, and numpy will select the value matching the first True condition. However, depending on your real use case you can sometimes do even better. Can you update your question to add another example of your more complex logic?

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

```
def helo(row):
    if "nok" in (row[0], row[1], row[2]):
        return "nok"
    elif "deact" in (row[0], row[1], row[2]):
        return "deact"
    else:
        return "ok"

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda e : helo(e), axis=1)
```

You can use pandas' apply function. Final df is given below.

```
col1    col2    col3    result
0   ok  ok  ok  ok
1   ok  nok nok nok
2   deact   ok  ok  deact
3   deact   ok  nok nok
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was trying to avoid hard coded columns, because size might varies. Of course I could use len(list(df)) to put as an index of the column.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use pandas .loc to create the result column.

```
df['result'] = 'ok'
df.loc[(df == 'deact').any(axis=1), 'result'] = 'deact'
df.loc[(df == 'nok').any(axis=1), 'result'] = 'nok'
```

Here's a link to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Result:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ok | ok | ok | ok |
| 1 | ok | nok | nok | nok |
| 2 | deact | ok | ok | deact |
| 3 | deact | ok | nok | nok |